# Excel Protect one autofilter column but allow for others

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to have a protected worksheet that has one of the Autofilters in a table protected from being changed, but allow the other Autofilters to be freely changed by the user.

Is this possible? My work around was that I hid the column that contains the Autofilter I don't want to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put all your "allowed-to-be-filtered" data in say columns A to F, then put the other that shouldn't be filtered in G +, then only select A to F, add filter, and set access rights for A to F only, it might work.